# SQL query to return one single row for each unique customer ID

Tags: sql-server, ssms

All columns (ID, Salesperson, Item, Type) in the `Todays_Sales` table.

My current query results shows:

```
ID      Salesperson     Item    Type        
---------------------------------------
75343   Mike Germain    3874    Credit          
75343   Ken Johnson     2590    Cash            
67850   Justin Anderson 6435    Check           
67850   Mike Germain    1228    Credit
```

I want my query result to instead show:

```
ID      Salesperson 1   Item 1  Type 1  Salesperson 2   Item 2  Type 2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
75343   Mike Germain    3874    Credit  Ken Johnson     2590    Cash
67850   Justin Anderson 6435    Check   Mike Germain    1228    Credit
```

Comment: Is there a well knows number of items?

Comment: I do not have a list of all items

Comment: For your results, are there always exactly two sets of (Salesperson, Item, Type)?  Are there ever only a single row with a particular ID? Are there ever more than two?  (e.g. 67850, Ken Johnson, 4456, Check).  In those case, what sort of result do you want?

Comment: In most cases there will be two sets, but rarely there can be 3 or 4 or even just one.  If there are more than 2, then I'd want it in the same format  just showing 3 more columns (e.g. Salesperson 3,Item 3, Type 3), etc.  If just one, results can just show with null or blank for the unneeded columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH
input(id,salesperson,item,type) AS (
          SELECT 75343, 'Mike Germain'   ,3874,'Credit'
UNION ALL SELECT 75343, 'Ken Johnson'    ,2590,'Cash'
UNION ALL SELECT 67850, 'Justin Anderson',6435,'Check'
UNION ALL SELECT 67850, 'Mike Germain'   ,1228,'Credit'
)
-- Common Table Expression above is just for data, don't use
-- in real query
,
-- begin WITH clause with this if selecting from table
input_w_seq AS (
SELECT
  id
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS seq
, salesperson
, item
, type
FROM input
)
SELECT
  id
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN salesperson END) AS salesperson_1
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN item        END) AS item_1
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN type        END) AS type_1
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN salesperson END) AS salesperson_2
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN item        END) AS item_2
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN type        END) AS type_2
FROM input_w_seq
GROUP BY
  id
ORDER BY
  id
;

id    |salesperson_1  |item_1|type_1|salesperson_2|item_2|type_2
67,850|Justin Anderson| 6,435|Check |Mike Germain | 1,228|Credit
75,343|Mike Germain   | 3,874|Credit|Ken Johnson  | 2,590|Cash
```

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions - steers me in the right direction as a new learner.